# dtypes changed when initialising a new DataFrame from another one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting, multiple-columns

Let's say that I have a DataFrame df1 with 2 columns: `a` with dtype `bool` and `b` with dtype `int64`. When I initialise a new DataFrame (`df1_bis`) from `df1`, columns `a` and `b` are automatically converted into objects, even if I force the dtype of `df1_bis`:

```
In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [True], 'b': [0]})
Out[3]:
      a  b
0  True  0

In [4]: df1.dtypes
Out[4]:
a     bool
b    int64
dtype: object

In [5]: df1_bis = pd.DataFrame(df1.values, columns=df1.columns,     dtype=df1.dtypes)
Out[6]:
      a  b
0  True  0

In [7]: df1_bis.dtypes
Out[7]:
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the `dtype` argument of DataFrame?

Comment: or `df1_bis = df1.copy()` (deep copy is by default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `numpy` that is causing the problem.  `pandas` is inferring the types from the numpy array.  If you convert to a list, you won't have the problem.

```
df1_bis = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(),
                       columns=df1.columns)


print(df1_bis)
print
print(df1_bis.dtypes)

      a  b
0  True  0

a     bool
b    int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

For me works:

```
df1_bis = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index)
#df1_bis = pd.DataFrame(df1)

print (df1_bis)
      a  b
0  True  0

print (df1_bis.dtypes)
a     bool
b    int64
dtype: object
```

But I think better is use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df1_bis = df1.copy()
```

If you want use `dtype`, you need works with `Series` because parameter `dtype` in [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) is for all columns:

```
df1_bis = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series(df1.a.values, dtype=df1.a.dtypes),
                        'b':pd.Series(df1.b.values, dtype=df1.b.dtypes)}
                       , index=df1.index)

print (df1_bis)
      a  b
0  True  0

print (df1_bis.dtypes)
a     bool
b    int64
dtype: object
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,5], 'b': [0,4]}, dtype=float)
print (df)
     a    b
0  1.0  0.0
1  5.0  4.0

print (df.dtypes)
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
```